# Pluralizing Quotations

Tags: grammatical-number, punctuation, quotations, quotation-marks

Is there a way to properly pluralize a quotation, if I *must* and can't just rearrange the sentence to avoid it (or do not wish to rearrange it for artistic purposes)?

Example:

> We exchanged many "I love you"s/ 'I love you's/ "I love you" 's.

Or would this simply be left unquoted?

Comment: They are actually *not literally quotes*.  We exchanged many I-love-yous and hand-holds and neck-sniffs.

Answer (score -2):

I personally think "I love you" should be a subject to be counted if it is to be a plural form. It's a sentence somebody said. So 'We exchanged many "I love you" will be okay. But if you want to emphasize it, you need to consider **"I love you"** as a subject to be countable. In that case, I'd recommend that you use a normal way to make a plural form: adding 's' like We exchanged many "I love you"s because 's means possessive case, not plural forms. Hope I helped you out.